# linux command to process part of line before and after a pattern differently

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

My original text is

```
11  2   CDTZ - b00264ab
36  37  CDTB - c2330001
```

I want output text to appear as

```
11  2   CDTZ - b0:02:64:ab
36  37  CDTB - c2:33:00:01
```

I have to add a colon after every 2 characters for the string that follows hyphen.

Is there any common text processing command to which I can instruct that

1. All string before (and including) hyphen should be untouched.
2. Insert colon after every 2 characters that follow hyphen.

In general, I have to process text before and after a pattern (hyphen here) differently.

**My efforts so far:**

- I have basic knowledge of `sed` and `awk`.
- If there was a way to do `sed` inside an `awk` then I would set `-` (hyphen)  as field separator in `awk` and do
  `sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//'` on `$2`, then print the whole line using `print $0`.

Comment: Are the multiple spaces or single tabs between the columns?

Comment: you can assume all separation as tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{gsub(/../,"&:",$NF); sub(/:$/,"",$NF);}1' file
11  2   CDTZ    -   b0:02:64:ab
36  37  CDTB    -   c2:33:00:01
```

- `gsub(/../,"&:",$NF)` will add trailing `:` to each couple or charecters.
- `sub(/:$/,"",$NF)` will remove the unwanted `:` at end of the last field which was added by previous `gsub`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks.

Comment: adding 1 in the awk command seems a little cryptic.If I remove 1 and add print $0 after last semi colon then effect is same . The difference is that I can send output to a file while 1 in your case does not allow re-directing output to a file. What do you think ?

Comment: @sumina You can _definitely_ just redirect the output to a new file with that `awk` command. Just add `>newfile` at the end.

Comment: yeah, that works . Don't know why it didn't when I ran that previously. BTW, what does 1 refer to in your command ?

Comment: @sumina It's a shortcut to writing `{ print }`, which is the same as `{ print $0 }`. Siva could just as well had used `sub(...); print` at the end of that `{ ... }` block.

Comment: ok. understood .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the hexadecimal number at the end is always eight characters:

```
$ sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)$/\1:\2:\3:\4/' file
11      2       CDTZ    -       b0:02:64:ab
36      37      CDTB    -       c2:33:00:01
```

Comment: That also works . Though, I intended to find a general manner to process text before and after a search pattern in line . So, awk solution is better .

Comment: @sumina Well, your question was very specific about what you wanted to do, with specific data shown. If you have other data that does not fulfill the requirements of this answer, than you did not show it. My answer _literally_ inserts a `:` between every second characters in the last column.

Comment: As I said earlier - both answers work . I can do not have power to upvote and I can only mark one with tick. Did you gave -1 to question ? Thanks for listening .

Comment: @sumina I did not vote on anything relating to this question.

Comment: when I posted, I got -1 then it became 0 after sometime and now it is again -1 . Stackexchange should tell user atleast who did it and be a little lenient .

Comment: @sumina See here about that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts

Comment: yeah, that tells it is anonymous . I suspect that there are experts who look down on beginners and quickly give negative votes . One should atleast leave a comment and a helpful opinion for user so that he won't repeat that mistake .

Comment: @sumina Our U&L Meta site contains a few questions about this, see e.g. https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=why+downvoted

Comment: ok . i try to ask general questions so that it is helpful for other users too . it sometimes happens that my requirement makes it more specific .